# How to calculate stress in a cylindrical-uniaxial-loaded bar with sudden changes in its diameter

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, stresses

How can I calculate the von Mises stress in the cross-section of a bar like this that is axially loaded?
[image]

Comment: If it was a uniform bar, how would you approach it? Then, consider each section...

Comment: I would just divide the load [F], over the area [A]. But I dont think it is right to apply that approach to the sections where the area where I'm applying the force is smaller than the diameter of the cylinder.

Comment: Note that I'm particularly interested on how stress behaves around the **steps** of the bar, not so much on the overall bar itself.

Comment: How sharp are the corners inside those steps? Not as critical in tension as bending, but stress concentration may be an issue if they are very sharp...

Comment: @JonathanRSwift They are not rounded at all, they are as sharp as the CNC tool that made the piece allowed to. But those are the kind of problems I'm concerned about.

Comment: ^The CNC tool that made them is certainly not infinitely sharp! I'd say that your point of failure will be at the root of the 20mm segment on the RHS, and there's no need to worry about the rest of the shaft, since that's the smallest diameter by a significant margin (it's 2/3rds of the next size up).

Comment: The biggest question is *why* are they not rounded at all? What design constraint is preventing you from putting a fillet/champher in that corner I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Oh, that's not a picture of my actual piece, that's just an image I found on google to give an idea of what the problem looks like. My piece has a 'more dangerous' design in which in have one section that changes by a factor of 4.

Comment: Can you upload an image of the part in question? And The mating parts that prevent addition of stress relief?

Answer (score 1):

Stress Concentration factors on the internal corner of a Stepped Shaft are well understood, and have some standardised calculations/equations: I'd recommend this excellent online calculator, which shows all the background equations further down the page. This  allows you to calculate the stress concentration factor in various loading conditions.

https://www.amesweb.info/StressConcentrationFactor/SteppedShaftWithShoulderFillet.aspx

You will see for yourself how reducing the fillet radius towards zero drastically raises the stress concentration factor, and you should try to remove the requirement for a 'sharp' corner if at all possible.

Here's an FEA rendering of the shaft illustrated in your question, showing how the root of the smallest diameter is the critical area (N.B. this does have a radius!)[image: FEA rendering showing stress concentration at root of stepped shaft.]

Answer (score 0):

You get two effects near the area of sudden changes in cross section.

1 - Stress concentration and contour lines of stress distribution.

2 - Stress wave propogation.

Sharp corners are stress concentration traps. Anticipating the path of stress and desgning the part's geometry according to that helps.

Both of these  items one and two affect the performance of the member significantly, specially under repetitive or shock loading.

There are computer simulation sofware that can analyze these up to a high level of precision.